# Selectable, scrollable output textarea

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

How do I create a text area that is scrollable, has a fixed height and allows marking the text?
HTML, JSF and PF4.0 elements are possible, linebreaks of the original text must be respected.

If I use `<p:inputTextarea>` and set disabled="true", when I mark the text it is like I cannot release the cursor. It will always continue marking whereever my cursor goes. Also, disabled seems to block me from using the scrollbar.

It is supposed to look similar to this but with an activated scrollbar (doesn't matter if text is greyed out):

[image: non-scrollable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do that with `p:inputTextarea`, so I've used HTML element when I've needed that, rendered instead of disabled textArea:

```
  <ui:fragment rendered="#{lorem.disabled}">
    <div style="max-width:150px;max-height:150px;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:auto;white-space:pre;">
      #{lorem.ipsum}
    </div>
  </ui:fragment>
  <p:inputTextArea value="#{lorem.ipsum}" rendered="#{!lorem.disabled}"/>
```

Comment: works pretty much as it is supposed to. But I can see an enabled scrollbar when the text is so small that no scrolling is needed. Can u tell me how I can change that?

Comment: What browser? 'auto' means the scroll will be not displayed when not needed, I have no scroll under FireFox and IE10.

Comment: mäh, you are right, they use the shitty IE9 here. Works on FF ;) workarounds for IE9 existent?

Comment: @dasLort I'm not sure, I think there were some questions about IE scroll bug on SO, but I can't remember if someone has found some good solution.